# .Net Core Web API not accepting a json string field value

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem whereby I would like to pass a json string as a field value but I keep getting `"The input was not valid"`. So to be clear I have an object in my front end that I use the below to pass to my API:

```
let j: Settings = {} as Settings;
j.user_settings_ID = object.user_settings_ID;
j.user_ID = object.user_ID;
j.user_filter = JSON.stringify(object.user_filter);
j.user_test_filter = JSON.stringify(object.user_test_filter);

fetch('api/Profile/UpdateProfileSettings/?id=' + object.user_settings_ID, {
    method: 'put',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    body: "'" + JSON.stringify(j) + "'",
}).then(data => {
    if (!data.ok) {
        alert("Failed");
    }           
}).catch((ex) => {
    alert("Failed");
});
```

In my API I have:

```
[HttpPut("[action]")]
public async Task<string> UpdateProfileSettings(int id, [FromBody] string obj)
{
    HttpClient clientRoute = new HttpClient();

    var response = await clientRoute.PutAsync("https://something.com/api/UserSettings/put/" + id, new StringContent(obj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return contents;
}
```

I don't have a problem when I set the `j.user_filter` and `j.user_test_filter` with any normal string, but I would like to put the `'jsonified'` string as the value for the field, but the Web API doesn't like it for some reason (probably because it isn't seeing it as a string but a json object perhaps)

If someone could help I would be most grateful.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I get the resultant JSON.stringify(j) string value and put that into Postman it works perfectly but not in my application, if that helps.

Comment: why are you using `"'"` before `JSON.stringify(j)` ? when are u getting ["The input was not valid"]. error?

Comment: @Niladri well that is how I have used it for other simple objects and it works. If you are using [FromBody] string in your API and not a model then that is the way to do it..apparently

Comment: @Niladri I am certain the issue is to do with me trying to pass a string which looks like json to my API that is causing the problem but I don't know how to fix it.
The fields being:

j.user_filter = JSON.stringify(object.user_filter);
j.user_test_filter = JSON.stringify(object.user_test_filter);

If I replace with just say:

j.user_filter = "TEST 1";
j.user_test_filter = TEST 2";

It works??

Comment: I didn't mention that the objects that I am trying to use JSON.stringify against are arrays?

Comment: JSON.stringify(j) returns a string itself not sure why are you adding a single quote before

Comment: @Niladri I require those or else I will get a 500 error. Don't forget I am passing raw json if I don't put those then null value will be passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after messing about with this for a long time, I came up with this 'solution'.

So as @Niladri pointed out the "'" before JSON.stringify(j) was a factor but was not the only thing that needed to be changed. The main problem was actually in the controller itself.

I had this previously in my controller:

```
        public async Task<string> UpdateProfileSettings(int id,[FromBody] string obj)
    {

        HttpClient clientRoute = new HttpClient();

        var response = await clientRoute.PutAsync("https://something.com/api/UserSettings/put/" + id, new StringContent(obj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return contents;
    }
```

But I had to change it to:

```
       public async Task<string> UpdateProfileSettings(int id,[FromBody] object obj)
    {

        HttpClient clientRoute = new HttpClient();

        var response = await clientRoute.PutAsync("https://something.com/api/UserSettings/put/" + id, new StringContent(obj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return contents;
    }
```

Notice the change of `[FromBody] string obj` to `[FromBody] object obj` and also
changed `StringContent(obj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))` to `StringContent(obj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))`

My previous method with "'" before JSON.stringify(j) works if your controller [FromBody] is of string type and you aren't looking to pump a string which looks like JSON into your controller.

I apologise if this is a bad explanation but tried my best and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to mcc20's own fix, but I didn't get that code to work. The 2.1 framework has Issues https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7609 and https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7799. I got this JSON post to complex class working in 2.1: client javascript is unchanged:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({ "name": document.getElementById('firstname').value, "email": document.getElementById('email').value, "captcha": grecaptcha.getResponse() });
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.ContentType = "application/json";

oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    else document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "not 4&200! : " + this.responseText;
};

oReq.open('POST', 'api/u');
oReq.send(payload);
```

and the controller has:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
//  [ApiController] // works either way
public class UController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> signUp()
    {
        String body;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        UserSignup user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSignup>(body);

        return user.email;
    }
}
```

I was trying something like `([FromBody] UserSignup user)` getting Mvc.SerializableError and "The input was not valid." Soon to be on https://github.com/Hover-Us/